# Is exposing a s3 secret access key in travis.yml file on an opensource project on Github a security risk?

Tags: security, github, amazon-s3

I don't know much about Amazon s3 but I assume something called secre_access_key probably should be a secret. I'm reviewing a .travis.yml of someone's opensource project on Github and it is exposed. Is this something that the author overlooked or does this simply not matter because other users can't do anything with it?

Comment: Yes, if the key is not invalid (revoked) it can be used to upload or delete files to the S3 bucket. I think the public AWS access key (kind of username) is also needed, but that one is typically not secret.

Answer (score 3):

Travis provides a [mechanism](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) for storing encrypted data in .travis.yml that only travis can decrypt. It that's what is in the file then I wouldn't worry (I'd still only do this for a locked down IAM set of credentials).

Assuming that's not what is in the file, Aws keys should definitely be secret. In the worse case scenario (the credentials are for the root aws user) it could allow full control of the aws account (ec2, rds etc. - not just s3)

It could also be more benign - for example if they are the credentials for a limited privilege user that can only read some files from a specific s3 bucket. I still wouldn't recommend checking in any credentials of any sort to a public repository.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I faced a problem a company named https://leakd.io/ captured my key and gave me an ethical warning message.

Please don't do that try environment var